# Does Oracle's XMLType support JDBC batch updates?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, batch-file, xmltype

Does Oracle's JDBC implementation support XMLType batch updates (via PreparedStatement.addBatch())?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research, it appears like a known limitation of Oracle's JDBC implementation is that it does not support "stream types" as bind variables (XMLType being a stream type).

According to their own [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/java.101/b10979/oraperf.htm#sthref1883):

> Oracle's implementation of standard update batching does not support stream types as bind values. (This is also true of Oracle update batching.) Any attempt to use stream types will result in an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Oracle types can tell how they're invoked, so the answer would be "yes".

The real question is: "What problem do you think that batch processing will introduce that real-time processing does not?"

Comment: I think bkent314 refers to submitting statements using JDBC's batching features (PreparedStatement.addBatch()) which is a big performance improvement over "single statement" execution

Comment: Yes, a_horse_with_no_name, exactly!  I should probably have put something to that effect in the question...

Comment: But that's the driver, not the type itself.  I still don't see how that is affected by XMLType.

Comment: I am only interested in what Oracle can do with regard to their JDBC implementation.  I thought that was implied in my question, but obviously not.  Sorry for the confusion.  I am going to tweak the question a little.